# While using holoviews in google Colab I get this error - cannot import name 'future_add_done_callback'

Tags: python, data-science, bokeh, holoviews, spectrogram

I am trying to plot a spectrogram from my Numpy array. I tried to look up stack overflow for a solution but could only find that the version of tornado might be needed to be downgraded but even that did not help. Can you please help me with my plottings. I am attaching my code below and the image of the error that I get.

```
# Plotting interactive plots - 
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

import os
os.environ['HV_DOC_HTML'] = 'true'
#%env HV_DOC_HTML=true

import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
hv.extension('bokeh')
output_notebook()
import imp
imp.reload(hv)

hv_spec = hv.Dataset(xr_spec)
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv_spec.to(hv.Image, ['time', 'freq'])
```

Images are here - 
[image: The error when i run the code]

[image: I also get an error when I try to install holoviews in google colab. This is the error message that I get.]

Comment: See also tips and discussion here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/967

Comment: @SandervandenOord when I try to follow your discussion, I still get the error while downloading holoviews in colab. I have uploaded its screenshot in the question at the very end. I hope you help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an outdated version of Tornado - `future_add_done_callback` has been added in 5.0.